# Here how does the word ''where'' play as its role?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, sentence-structure

in this following sentence, what does the word ''where'' mean?
How should I take the word ''where''?

''How is it ever possible to speak of the annihilation of a self, or soul, or ego, **where** no such thing is to be found?''

Page- 9

''Fundamentals of Buddhism''

by
Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: It is impossible for us to properly analyze translations like this. Did you look up the word where in the dictionary? Please do.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conjunction (it links two clauses), and the meaning is "in the case that" or "if".

> How can we talk about the annihilation of *the self*, if *the self* does not exist?

See Cambridge dictionary's [discussion of this word](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/where)